# Windows Live oAuth wrap for contacts?

Tags: php, oauth, msdn

I would like to know if the [oAuth wrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff752204.aspx) authentication facility by windows live is just for messenger connect or what? 
Can it be used for Live Contacts API?
I am trying to fetch addressbook from live contacts. How can i do that? 
Microsoft's msdn documentation on various APIs sucks to the core!! They doesnt even have any specific working PHP example for this. 
Can somebody redirect me to the well organized documentation/tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've figured this out yet, but I am looking into it as well. I don't have a working sample yet, but the answer is YES, OAuth WRAP can be used for the Live Contacts API as well as any other Messenger Connect APIs. It's actually fairly straightforward if you've used OAuth before. You would obtain authorization as with any other provider (eg. Facebook, LinkedIn, Google, etc.), and then obtain an access token:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750952.aspx

You would then pass that access token in the Authorization header (`curl_setopt`, `CURLOPT_HTTP_HEADER`) and continue with the REST call as if you had authorized using the Live SDK.

Comment: Thanks but i got this sorted out. I am using delegated authentication to fetch Live contacts. It seems pretty fast and straight forward.

Comment: @Forte, can you elaborate on house you finished your implementation? I have an oAuth enabled app, and many users are requesting using their existing hotmail/live account to access.  My app is CodeIgniter/PHP backend, just curious if you got anywhere with your dev.